# The inserted code has extra blank lines

Tags: listings

I'm using listings to format blocks of code in my xeLaTeX.When I insert this picture into Anki's card, the inserted code has extra blank lines. Following is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox,listings}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Consolas}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{framed}

\definecolor{background}{HTML}{EEEEEE}
\definecolor{comments}{HTML}{868686}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{139,0,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{0,0,139}
\definecolor{chartreuse}{RGB}{127,255,0}
\definecolor{drakgreen}{RGB}{0,128,0}
\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{238,239,240}


\lstset{
language=[LaTeX]Tex,
keywordstyle=\color{darkblue},
texcsstyle=*\color{blue},
basicstyle=\normalfont\ttfamily,
commentstyle=\color{comments}\ttfamily,
stringstyle=\rmfamily,
frame=lrtb,
%numbers=left,
numbers=none,
numberstyle=\scriptsize,
numbersep=8pt,
showstringspaces=false,
breaklines=true,
frameround=ftff,
frame=none,
captionpos=t,
belowcaptionskip=0em,
belowskip=0em,
literate=
*{\{}{{\textcolor{darkred}{\{}}}{1}
{\}}{{\textcolor{darkred}{\}}}}{1}
{[}{{\textcolor{darkred}{[}}}{1}
{]}{{\textcolor{darkred}{]}}}{1},
}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
language=[LaTeX]Tex,
extendedchars=true, 
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
numbers=none,
keywordstyle=\color{darkblue},
keywordstyle=[2]\color{blue},
keywordstyle=[3]\color{darkblue},
keywordstyle=[4]\color{drakgreen},
alsoletter = {!},
keywords=[2]{definecolor,node,addplot},
keywords=[3]{usepackage},
keywords=[4]{begin,end,document,figure,figure*,axis}
}

\tcbuselibrary{listings,skins,breakable}
\newtcblisting{mycode}{
arc=0mm,
top=0mm,
bottom=0mm,
left=3mm,
right=0mm,
width=\textwidth,
boxrule=1pt,
colback=lightgray,
listing only,
%listing options={style=mystyle},
breakable
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mycode}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw [gray] (0,0) circle (2pt)
(1,1) circle (2pt)
(2,1) circle (2pt)
(2,0) circle (2pt);
\draw (0,0) .. controls (1,1) and (2,1) .. (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{mycode}

When executed, that is, run via pdflatex or via latex followed by dvips, the resulting will contain something that looks like this:
\end{document}
```

[image]

How to eliminate the extra blank lines at the top?

After commenting out this line‘listing only’, it draws a picture of this code.

[image]

Comment: Ŷou should test your own example _before_  posting it ...

Comment: Sorry, the code has been modified.

Comment: (i) showed image is not provided by your code. (ii) why you use code from received answer in your question? Now the question is unclear what is your problem. (iii) since received answer apparently solve your problem, it will be nice to up-vote it and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
\newtcblisting{mycode}{
    arc=0mm,
    top=0mm,
    bottom=0mm,
    left=3mm,
    right=0mm,
    width=\textwidth,
    boxrule=1pt,
    colback=lightgray,
%   listing only,
    listing options={style=mystyle},
    breakable
}
```

The `listing only` option is the problem.

Comment: I tried it according to your method, still the same.

Comment: After commenting out this line, it draws a picture of this code.

Comment: As far as I see the two lines `listing only` and `breakable` are problematic with `standalone`